# Typo3 use of <f:link.page pageUid="xx" > in HTML content and typoscriptObjectPath

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I want to use links with <f:link> in HTML element inside handler and in Typoscript with typoscriptObjectPath, for example:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="13" >Test Page Link</f:link.page>
```

But they always appear to me as plain text.
I'm using Typo3 11 and Fluid Template.
Do you have to activate something so that it renders as it was done before with the old old link parser?

Let's see if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get a text parsed as HTML, just use [`f:format.html()`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Html.html) in your Fluid Template. It renders a string by passing it to a TYPO3 parseFunc. By default lib.parseFunc_RTE is used to parse the string.

Comment: I tried doing something like:

`<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">
 <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.redesp" />
</f:format.html>`

And in the object I have:

`lib.redesp = TEXT
lib.redesp.value (
<f:link.page 13 >Test Page Link</f:link.page>`


But nothing is rendered.
Totally lost.

Comment: Ah... Your cObject is returning the HTML... Then, you can use a `FLUIDTEMPLATE`-cObject instead of `TEXT`. You can define a little `template` directly in TypoScript, too: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#template

Answer (score 0):

I made it.

Set the links in Typoscript this way:

```
lib.redesp = TEXT
lib.redesp.value = <a href="t3://page?uid=13">Test Link</a>
```

And in the Fluid template set:

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.redesp"/>
</f:format.html>
```

Don't know if this is the best way, but it works.